# What is the SI Unit for intercept of a graph

Tags: si-units

I have a graph that i drew and i got all the point and a question came up that what is SI Unit for intercept of a graph.

I have no idea what the answer is. (I'm a total newbie in Physics)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such thing as the "SI Unit for intercept of a graph", just like that. The unit will depend on what precisely you are plotting, as the intercept will have the same units as whatever the y-axis (vertical axis) of your plot represents.

So, ask yourself, what does my vertical axis represent? What are the SI coordinates of that magnitude?

As an example, if you are plotting a graph of speed as a function of time, with time on the x-axis and speed on the y-axis, the SI unit of the intercept will be that of speed (m/s).